# Test for convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to test the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

I think ratio test or comparison test is doable. But for ratio test, I cannot calculate the limit value.

Comment: The $n$th term doesn't go to $0$.

Comment: A more interesting question would be if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(n!)^{-1/n}$ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $n! > 2^n \implies a_n = (n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}> 2 \implies a_n $ doesn't converge to $0$, hence your series not convergent. Hope it's clear now...

Comment: It's enough that $n!\geq1$

Comment: I get $n!^\frac{1}{n} > 2 $. I think this is a divergent series. But the divergence test do not work..

Comment: @eulerisgod No your sum is "smaller" than $1+1+1+1...$, which tends to $\infty$. So the original sum diverges too.

Comment: get it!! super thanks!! :)

Comment: @eulerisgod: My pleasure...

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}\implies \log(a_n)=\frac{1}{n}\log(n!)$$ Using Stirling approximation twice and continuing with Taylor series, you would find that

$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{\log (2 \pi  n)}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=e^{\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)}=1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1-\log (2 \pi  n)}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$